# How to search for an element in array in Tikz?

Tags: arrays, tikzset

I am trying to pass a value (first input argument) and an array (second input argument) to Tikzset and I want to check if the value is in the array. Each time I am running the code, the array is read as a whole and not element-wise.
Here, *colorfill* is to do the search, and then to call other Tikzsets I defined prior. When I am using Ifnum with only the value as input and a number everything works just fine, but I am struggling with array input.

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth,scale=0.8}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, on grid,>={Stealth[inset=0pt,length=6pt,angle'=28,round]},fill fraction/.style n args={2}{path picture={
        \fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.center) -- (path picture bounding box.south)  arc [start angle=-90, delta angle=-100, radius=1] -- cycle;
        \fill[#2] (path picture bounding box.center) -- (path picture bounding box.south)  arc [start angle=-90, delta angle=100, radius=1] -- cycle;
        }}
,fill fraction2/.style n args={1}{path picture={
        \fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.center) -- (path picture bounding box.south)  arc [start angle=-90, delta angle=-180, radius=1] -- cycle;
        }}
        ]
        
\tikzset{
redfill/.code args={}{
\definecolor{mycolour1}{rgb}{1,0,0}%
\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=mycolour1}
  }
}
\tikzset{
greenfill/.code args={}{
\definecolor{mycolour2}{rgb}{0,1,0}%
\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=mycolour2}
  }
}
\tikzset{
bluefill/.code args={}{
\definecolor{mycolour3}{rgb}{0,0,1}%
\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=mycolour3}
  }
}

\tikzset{colorfill/.code n args={2}{
\foreach \x in {#2}{
\ifnum \x = #1
        \tikzset{greenfill={}}
    \else
        \tikzset{redfill={}}
    \fi
}

}}

\def\greenstatesind{
{2,4}
}
\def\redstatesind{
3
}

\node[state,initial](q1){$q^{1}$};
\foreach \i[evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i-1),evaluate=\i as \k using int(\i)] in {2,...,5}{
    \node[state, right of=q\j, colorfill={\k},{\greenstatesind}] (q\i){$q^{\i}$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd rather `scale` the `tikzpicture` directly instead of using an `adjustbox` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of minor issues like invisible spaces and so on, which are easy to fix. If you want to use a loop to see if a given element is contained in the list, there two more subtle issues:

1. If one wants to follow closely the code that you provide, one has to use the `/.expanded` key in order not to confuse pgf.
2. If you use `\tikzset{}` in a `foreach` loop, it does not work because `\tikzset` is local and `foreach` uses groups. However, the `/.list` key does not form these groups and can be used instead.

This code implements these changes, and also completes the fragment that was provided to a complete document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth,scale=0.8}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, on grid,>={Stealth[inset=0pt,length=6pt,angle'=28,round]},fill fraction/.style n args={2}{path picture={
            \fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.center) -- (path picture bounding box.south)  arc [start angle=-90, delta angle=-100, radius=1] -- cycle;
            \fill[#2] (path picture bounding box.center) -- (path picture bounding box.south)  arc [start angle=-90, delta angle=100, radius=1] -- cycle;
            }}
    ,fill fraction2/.style n args={1}{path picture={
            \fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.center) -- (path picture bounding box.south)  arc [start angle=-90, delta angle=-180, radius=1] -- cycle;
            }}
            ]
            
    \tikzset{
    redfill/.code={%  args={}{....} is at the very least unnecessary
    \definecolor{mycolour1}{rgb}{1,0,0}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=mycolour1}
      }
    }
    \tikzset{%
    greenfill/.code={%  args={}{....} is at the very least unnecessary
    \definecolor{mycolour2}{rgb}{0,1,0}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=mycolour2}
    }
    }
    \tikzset{
    bluefill/.code={%  args={}{....} is at the very least unnecessary
    \definecolor{mycolour3}{rgb}{0,0,1}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=mycolour3}
      }
    }
    
    \tikzset{colorfill sub/.code={\ifnum\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/colorfill item}=#1\relax
            \tikzset{greenfill}% greenfill has no argument
        \else
            \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/redfill}% redfill has no argument
        \fi},
        colorfill item/.initial=0,
        colorfill/.code n args={2}{%
        \tikzset{colorfill item=#1,colorfill sub/.list=#2}%
         }    
    }
    
    \def\greenstatesind{%
    {2,4}%
    }
    \def\redstatesind{%
    {3}%
    }
    
    \node[state,initial](q1){$q^{1}$};
    \foreach \i[evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i-1),evaluate=\i as \k using int(\i)] in {2,...,5}{
        \node[state,right of=q\j,colorfill/.expanded={\k}{\greenstatesind}% removed comma and added /.expanded
        ] (q\i){$q^{\i}$};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that it is very likely that the task can be simplified quite a bit. pgf has `\pgfutil@in@` which is a low-level membership test and get used in pgf quite a bit. Whether it provides a user interface for such tests I do not know.

Comment: Thanks! One question: Why q2 whose index is the greenstateind is red instead of green?

Comment: Because all I did was to implement your loop, i.e. fix technical issues. It is still  not entirely correct at the conceptional level. As I wrote, it is much better to design a membership test based on `\pgfutil@in@`. I guess you will want to bark at me, but before doing that please realize that this makes you bark at every single user who cared to look at your question.